# Multiple hierarchy in mondrian says Hierarchy not found

Tags: schema, pentaho, mondrian

I have following Dimension in mondrian schema. Mondrian on creating connection says

mondrian.olap.MondrianException: Mondrian Error:Internal error: Hierarchy '[Product]' not found

```
<Dimension name="Product" foreignKey="item_id">
    <Hierarchy hasAll="true" primaryKey="item_code" primaryKeyTable="m_item_master">
        <Join leftKey="item_code" rightKey="item_code">
            <Table name="m_item_master"/> <!--dummy_master--> <!--m_item_master-->
            <Table name="m_item_relation"/>
        </Join>
        <Level name="Department" table="m_item_relation" column="department"/>
        <Level name="Class" table="m_item_relation" column="category"/>
        <Level name="Item" table="m_item_master" column="item_code" ordinalColumn="item_code" nameColumn="name" uniqueMembers="true" type="Numeric"/>
    </Hierarchy>

    <Hierarchy name="Base Item" hasAll="false" primaryKey="item_code" primaryKeyTable="m_item_master">
        <Join leftKey="item_code" rightKey="item_code">
            <Table name="m_item_master"/> <!--dummy_master--> <!--m_item_master-->
            <Table name="m_item_relation"/>
        </Join>
        <Level name="Department" table="m_item_relation" column="department" captionColumn="department"/>
        <Level name="Item" table="m_item_master" column="item_code" ordinalColumn="item_code" nameColumn="name" uniqueMembers="true" captionColumn="name" type="Numeric"/>
        <Property name="Price" table="m_item_master" column="price" />
    </Hierarchy>
</Dimension>
```

I am using Mondrian-4.0.0-SNAPSHOT version and tried the same with latest mondrian 4.2.0.0-204 version as well.

Note:
Moreover I am getting this Error during mondrian connection creation itself. So it doesn't concern with any MDX query passed to it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. This is the what the mistake I found. For the clarification, **Mondrian do support multiple hierarchy**, but to the above schema we seems to have a different problem with the associated roles.

```
<Role name="myrole">
    <SchemaGrant access="none">
        <CubeGrant cube="Transaction" access="all">
            <HierarchyGrant hierarchy="[Product]" access="custom" rollupPolicy="partial">
                <MemberGrant member="[Product].[Cottage Foods]" access="all"/>
                <MemberGrant member="[Product].[Vegetables]" access="all"/>
                ....
            </HierarchyGrant>
            ....
        </CubeGrant>
    </SchemaGrant>
</Role>
```

In the above role, though the default hierarchy takes the name of the dimension in mondrian, we have to specify them as [Dimension.Hierarchy] in roles but not just Hierarchy name if you have multiple hierarchy within the Dimension. In our case, it should be as below.

```
<Role name="myrole">
    <SchemaGrant access="none">
        <CubeGrant cube="Transaction" access="all">
            <HierarchyGrant hierarchy="[Product.Product]" access="custom" rollupPolicy="partial">
                <MemberGrant member="[Product.Product].[Cottage Foods]" access="all"/>
                <MemberGrant member="[Product.Product].[Vegetables]" access="all"/>
                ....
            </HierarchyGrant>
            ....
        </CubeGrant>
    </SchemaGrant>
</Role>
```

This solves the above problem.